# Microsoft SQL divide result from two queries/tables, do I need a join? Or would work SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have here two SQL queries, the one is counting the active user and the other the closed incidents.And I need to divide the result from the two queries in one querie.

Counting active user from last moth:

```
Select COUNT(*)
 From (
        Select distinct [Person - Benutzerkennung], Concat(DATEPART(year,[Erstellungszeitpunkt]), '.', DATEPART(month,[Erstellungszeitpunkt])) as Erstellungsmonat, '1' as Personen
        From [View_LSS_Reporting_Cost rates]
        where (FinancialManagementObjekt_Typ = 'Person')
 ) as innerTable
where Erstellungsmonat = (Concat(DATEPART(year,GETDATE()), '.', DATEPART(month,GETDATE())-1))
```

And this counting the closed 'Incidents' from last month:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [LSS_SATTLER_PROD].[dbo].[View_LSS_Reporting_01 Incident Management(692)]
 
Where ([Phase - name] like '07 Abschliessen')
 
and ([Abschlusszeitpunkt] > (dateadd(m,-1,getdate())))
```

A friend told me I need to create a join for this. But would work this code with Microsoft SQL, with a simple SELECT? I can not check it at the moment, I would be very thank full for any help!

```
SELECT

(SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [LSS_SATTLER_PROD].[dbo].[View_LSS_Reporting_01 Incident Management(692)]
 
Where ([Phase - name] like '07 Abschliessen')
 
and ([Abschlusszeitpunkt] > (dateadd(m,-1,getdate()))))

/

(Select COUNT(*)
 From (
 
 
        Select distinct [Person - Benutzerkennung], Concat(DATEPART(year,[Erstellungszeitpunkt]), '.', DATEPART(month,[Erstellungszeitpunkt])) as Erstellungsmonat, '1' as Personen
        From [View_LSS_Reporting_Cost rates]
        where (FinancialManagementObjekt_Typ = 'Person')
 ) as innerTable
where Erstellungsmonat = (Concat(DATEPART(year,GETDATE()), '.', DATEPART(month,GETDATE())-1)))
```

Or this should to the same?

```
SELECT
(Select COUNT(*)
 From (
 
 
        Select distinct [Person - Benutzerkennung], Concat(DATEPART(year,[Erstellungszeitpunkt]), '.', DATEPART(month,[Erstellungszeitpunkt])) as Erstellungsmonat, '1' as Personen
        From [View_LSS_Reporting_Cost rates]
        where (FinancialManagementObjekt_Typ = 'Person')
 ) as innerTable
where Erstellungsmonat = (Concat(DATEPART(year,GETDATE()), '.', DATEPART(month,GETDATE())-1)))
as active_user,

(SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [LSS_SATTLER_PROD].[dbo].[View_LSS_Reporting_01 Incident Management(692)]
 
Where ([Phase - name] like '07 Abschliessen')
 
and ([Abschlusszeitpunkt] > (dateadd(m,-1,getdate())))) as closed_incidents

closed_incidents/active_user
```

Comment: Your queries don't really make sense.  One has a filter on `'Person'`.  The other doesn't.  They have different date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a single query and conditional aggregation.  It is something like this:

```
select (count distinct case when [Phase - name] like '07 Abschliessen' then [Person - Benutzerkennung] end) * 1.0 /
        count(distinct [Person - Benutzerkennung])
       ) as ratio
from [View_LSS_Reporting_Cost rates]
where FinancialManagementObjekt_Typ = 'Person' and
      datediff(month, Erstellungsmonat, getdate()) = 1
```